# Vue.js google reCaptcha callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha

I am trying to get recaptcha callback working with vue.js in a component. The captcha itself does work, but not the callback that I define in the `data-callback` attribute.

I've tried everything I could think of, but I still get the `ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: dothisthat` error.

Here is the component

```
<script>
    function dothisthat (){
            alert(312);
        }
</script>

<template>
    <div class="well main-well">
        <h4>Captcha</h4>
        <p class="small">You must complete the captcha to finish your booking.</p>
        <div id="captcha-wrapper">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" :data-sitekey="captchaKey" data-callback="dothisthat"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
     function dothisthat (){
        alert(123);
    }
    import * as filters from '../../../filters';
    import Translation from '../../../Translation';

    export default {
        name: 'Captcha',
        props: {
        },
        computed: {
            captchaKey: function() {
                return this.$store.getters.captcha;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            dothisthat: function(){
                return function() {
                    console.log("123");
                };
            }
        },
        mounted(){

            function dothisthat() {
                alert(123);
            }
            $(function() {
                function dothisthat() {
                    alert(123);
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Not one of the `dothisthat` functions are getting called. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `:data-callback="dothisthat"`?

Comment: comes back with ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: function boundFn(a) {
    var l = arguments.length;
    return l
      ? l > 1
        ? fn.apply(ctx, arguments)
        : fn.call(ctx, a)
      : fn.call(ctx)
  }

Answer (score 37):

I came across this problem too and it took me 2 days to solve it.

So I will provide here a general answer for integrating recaptcha with vue.js from scratch step by step, to be an easy guide for people who will be in the same situation in the future (I am supposing vue-cli is used here).

> **Note:** I am using here the invisible recaptcha but the process is pretty similar to the normal one

**Step 1:**

add the recaptcha javascript api to your index.html

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

**Step 2:**

make a component called `Recaptcha` or whatever you want to call it (making a component will make your code easier to read, easier to maintain and easier to add recaptcha to more than one page if you need)

**Recaptcha.vue**

```
<template>
  <div 
  id="g-recaptcha"
  class="g-recaptcha"
  :data-sitekey="sitekey">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      sitekey: '6LfAEj0UAAAAAFTGLqGozrRD8ayOy*********',
      widgetId: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    execute () {
      window.grecaptcha.execute(this.widgetId)
    },
    reset () {
      window.grecaptcha.reset(this.widgetId)
    },
    render () {
      if (window.grecaptcha) {
        this.widgetId = window.grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
          sitekey: this.sitekey,
          size: 'invisible',
          // the callback executed when the user solve the recaptcha
          callback: (response) => {
            // emit an event called verify with the response as payload
            this.$emit('verify', response)
            // reset the recaptcha widget so you can execute it again
            this.reset() 
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // render the recaptcha widget when the component is mounted
    this.render()
  }
}
</script>
```

**Step 3:**

Import the recaptcha component and add it to your page (parent component).

**page.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Parent component (your page)</h1>
    <button @click="executeRecaptcha">execute recaptcha</button>
    <!-- listen to verify event emited by the recaptcha component -->
    <recaptcha ref="recaptcha" @verify="submit"></recaptcha>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Recaptcha from 'recaptcha'
export default {
  components: {
    Recaptcha
  },
  methods: {
    // send your recaptcha token to the server to verify it
    submit (response) {
      console.log(response)
    },
    // execute the recaptcha widget
    executeRecaptcha () {
      this.$refs.recaptcha.execute()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: just an add on, you can use a retry mechanism for recaptcha render function if you are deferring  recaptcha script.

Comment: Why are you using both `id="g-recaptcha"` and `class="g-recaptcha"`? Can you just use the `id` attribute  `id="g-recaptcha" ` without `class` attribute?

Comment: @stanimirsp you can remove the `class` but the `id` is required in order to reference it in the `window.grecaptcha.render` function. I don't know why I added the class there LOL. I think I just copied the code from the documentation like that.

Comment: Thanks Abdelaziz Mokhnache, this is the best solution. Very organized and dynamic.
 thanks again man.

Comment: @AbhishekParmar How can I try the retrying mechanism? Do you have any code sample?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not using component, but I had the same problem, and finally I resolve it like this:

HTML

```
<div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha"></div>
<button id="submit" @click="validate">Submit</button>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

JS

```
// ...
mounted: function() {
    this.initReCaptcha();
},
methods: {
    initReCaptcha: function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            if(typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined') {
                self.initReCaptcha();
            }
            else {
                grecaptcha.render('recaptcha', {
                    sitekey: 'SITE_KEY',
                    size: 'invisible',
                    badge: 'inline',
                    callback: self.submit
                });
            }
        }, 100);
    },
    validate: function() {
        // your validations...
        // ...
        grecaptcha.execute();
    },
    submit: function(token) {
        console.log(token);
    }
},
```

Comment: initReCaptcha method did the trick! Thanks. Instead of submitting on recaptcha success callback, i did set my form variable in callback so i post it to my api.

callback: function (response) {
    self.form.g_recaptcha_response = response;
}

Comment: It should be the ```window.grecaptcha```. Isn't it?

Comment: Using setTimeout for dependency load is moveton. You need to use load callbacks, events or promises. Otherwise network latency can break your application anyway. Even with delay 100 milliseconds

Answer (score 14):

**Easiest Solution:**

Html:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key" data-callback="myRecaptchaMethod">
</div>
```

Vue:

```
methods: {
    myRecaptchaMethod: function(response) {
        console.log(response); 
        // this is google's code verifying the user is human'
        // that you check with google on the backend.
    }
}

mounted: function() {
    window.myRecaptchaMethod = this.myRecaptchaMethod;
}
```

Done

Comment: This is so much easier and works without issue. It's also easy to convert to Vue3's composition API.

Comment: very amazing, im using this on vue script setup. work well, thankyou master.

Answer (score 4):

If you're only looking for the response value of recaptcha in order to validate it on server side, a simple solution is to put your recaptcha element in a form and get the response value from the target element of the submit `event`.

```
<form class="container"
  @submit="checkForm"
  method="post"
>

... // other elements of your form 

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>

<p>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
</form>
```

And in `checkForm` method:

```
methods : {
        checkForm: function (event) {
            recaptcha_response_value = event.target['g-recaptcha-response'].value

           ...
         }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem I had with the other solutions is that it sometimes tries to execute the `window.grecaptcha.render` when ReCaptcha isn't fully loaded. The only way to check that according to their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render) is to use an `onload` method.

This example below is how i've used it, ofcourse you could customize what you do with the callback.

**ReCaptcha.Vue:**

```
<template>
    <div ref="grecaptcha"></div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: ['sitekey'],

        methods: {

            loaded(){

                window.grecaptcha.render(this.$refs.grecaptcha, {
                    sitekey: this.sitekey,
                    callback: (response) => {

                        this.$emit('input', response);

                    },
                });

            },

        },

        mounted(){

            /**
             * Set Recapchat loaded function
             */
            window.ReCaptchaLoaded = this.loaded;

            /**
             * Set Recaptcha script in header
             */
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=ReCaptchaLoaded&render=explicit';
            document.head.appendChild(script);

        }

    }
</script>
```

**Usage**:

```
<ReCaptcha sitekey="KEY" v-model="fields.g_recaptcha_response.value" />
```

Comment: I ran into an issue where this was still generating the error 'Uncaught TypeError: grecaptcha.render is not a function" so I added script.async = true and script.defer = true and it eliminated it

Comment: The solution to the `grecaptcha.render is not a function` problem is that there is a `ready` method available in `window.grecaptcha` that you call with a callback function - so, first you wait for the `onload` to finish, and _then_ you wait for the `ready` function to call you back. 

I think I'll add an answer...

Comment: I get `ERROR for site owner: Invalid key type` even though my key works fine when used in the header via template like this `<script id='recaptcha' src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={{ CAPTCHA_SITEKEY }}"></script> `

Answer (score 3):

The previous answers are good but I wanted a drop-in component with no fussing around with scripts and async loading, so I made a simple component myself.

### TL;DR

1. see this gist
2. copy the `Recaptcha2.vue` file into your source tree
3. add `<recaptcha2>` into your Vue app

### Detail

https://gist.github.com/aellerton/92f33cef04a1df76636a658571e07724

It took a bit of messing around to get the recaptcha script to load and then initialise. As I mentioned in a comment to another answer on this question, there is first the `onload` callback *and then* the `grecaptcha.ready` function that can call your function to say "yep everything is ready for you to call `render` now".

Which is very nice of Google to provide that functionality, even though I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Wrapping all that up in a function looks like this (it's TypeScript but you can remove the type stuff and it's just JavaScript):

```js
function loadRecaptcha(callback: () => void) {
  let win = window as any
  if (win && !win.grecaptcha) {
    let recaptchaScript = document.createElement('script')
    document.head.appendChild(recaptchaScript)
    recaptchaScript.onload = () => {
      // At this point the recaptcha script has loaded but the
      // code in it as not completed loading. Fortunately there's
      // a "ready" function in there that can tell us when it's done.
      let win = window as any
      win.grecaptcha.ready(() => {
        callback()
      })
    }
    recaptchaScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js')
  } else {
    callback()
  }
}
```

Then the component itself is much simpler - it calls that function in `mounted()` and runs `grecaptcha.render` to create a recaptcha dynamically. No global functions required.

Using the component, in its barest form, looks like this:

```
  <div>
    <p>A tiny recaptcha demo</p>
    <recaptcha2 @change="robotChange"></recaptcha2>
    <p>Is human? {{isHuman}}
    <button :disabled="isSendDisabled">Send now</button>
  </div>
```

More details in [the gist](https://gist.github.com/aellerton/92f33cef04a1df76636a658571e07724)

Comment: The `ready` callback was necessary for what I was doing.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 2):

Just use vue-recaptcha https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha

npm install --save vue-recaptcha

```
<vue-recaptcha
  @verify="onVerify"
  :sitekey="this.key"
  :loadRecaptchaScript='true' // vue-recaptcha will inject <script src='//google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script> in head
  @expired="onCaptchaExpired"
  ref="recaptcha"
 ></vue-recaptcha>

import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';

export default {
  components: {
    VueRecaptcha
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        login: null,
        recaptcha: null,
      },
      key: // your sitekey
    };
  },     
  methods: {
    onVerify(response) {
      this.user.recaptcha = response;
    },
    onCaptchaExpired: function () {
      this.$refs.recaptcha.reset();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The above solution is the most simplest way to use recaptcha, but that will not work if you try to pass sitekey using `:siteKey`. `vue-recaptcha` tag accepts `siteKey` attribute i.e. without `:`, and thus you cannot pass  siteKey dynamically. Abdelaziz Mokhnache solution looks more promising and organized. Gonna try that out.

Comment: No, vue-recaptcha accepts :sitekey with :

Comment: Not sure why but that didn't worked for me :( .
Abdelaziz Mokhnache solution, worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

```
in Vue Component :
```

in template : html

```
<template>
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Email : </label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input v-model="email" id="email"  type="email" class="form-control"  value="" required autofocus>


            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong></strong>
                                </span>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
            Password :
        </label>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input v-model="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control"  required>


            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong></strong>
                                </span>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
            <div class="form-check">

                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="remember" v-model="remember">

                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                   Remember me
                </label>
                <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LehfpsUAAAAAIf3hvWNrGvat8o4lypZh_p6snRH"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Login with google</a>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Login
            </button>

            <a class="btn btn-link" href="">
                Forgot Your Password?
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and javascript :

```
<script>
import swal from 'sweetalert';
export default {
   data(){

       return {
           email: '',
           password: '',
           remember: ''
       }

   },
    mounted: function() {
        this.initReCaptcha();
    },
    methods: {
        onSubmit(event) {

            let recaptcha_response_value = event.target['g-recaptcha-response'].value;
            console.log(recaptcha_response_value);
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('email' , this.email);
            formData.append('password' , this.password);
            formData.append('remember' , this.remember);
            formData.append('g-recaptcha-response' , recaptcha_response_value);
            axios.post('/login' , formData)
                .then(
                    function(res){
                        swal('ورود شما موفقیت آمیز بود');
                    }
                )
                .catch(function(err){
                    swal('ایمیل یا کلمه عبور اشتباه است یا اینکه هنوز ثبت نام نکرده اید');
                    console.log(err);
                });

        }
    }

}
```